# JMeter - Changing user defined variables from command line

Tags: command-line, jmeter

I'm trying to update a "user defined variable" in a jmeter test plan using the command line

```
jmeter -n -t SimpleJmxExample.jmx -l log.jtl -Jtestproperty=202
```

[image]

as you can see I'm using the -J argument. However it doesn't seem to make any difference? Is there a better/more accepted way of passing in different variables for a test plan?

Here is my jmx file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.1">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1358160198000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1358160198000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <HTTPSampler guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSampler" testname="Test Http Response Code" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">httpstat.us</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/${testproperty}</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSampler>
        <hashTree>
          <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
              <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">max-age=0</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="Accept-Language" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Language</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">en-US,en;q=0.8</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip,deflate,sdch</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="Accept-Charset" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Charset</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </HeaderManager>
          <hashTree/>
          <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
            <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
            <objProp>
              <name>saveConfig</name>
              <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
                <time>true</time>
                <latency>true</latency>
                <timestamp>true</timestamp>
                <success>true</success>
                <label>true</label>
                <code>true</code>
                <message>true</message>
                <threadName>true</threadName>
                <dataType>true</dataType>
                <encoding>false</encoding>
                <assertions>true</assertions>
                <subresults>true</subresults>
                <responseData>false</responseData>
                <samplerData>false</samplerData>
                <xml>true</xml>
                <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
                <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
                <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
                <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
                <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
                <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
                <bytes>true</bytes>
              </value>
            </objProp>
            <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
          </ResultCollector>
          <hashTree/>
          <Arguments guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
              <elementProp name="testproperty" elementType="Argument">
                <stringProp name="Argument.name">testproperty</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value">200</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </Arguments>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Well, with `-J` argument you are setting **PROPERTY**, and in [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) config - **VARIABLE**. It will define two [different entities](https://blog.novatec-gmbh.de/how-to-pass-command-line-properties-to-a-jmeter-testplan/), although having the same name, they will have different values.

In your situation you can do the following.

1. Set jmeter property value in command-line as above in your question

   `...-Jtestproperty=202`
2. In UDV config set variable with value from property:

   `testproperty = ${__property(testproperty,,)}`

   or

   `testproperty = ${__P(testproperty,)}`
3. Use `${testproperty}` further in the script.

As well you can possibly do the same wihout using variable and simply refer property as `{__P(testproperty,)}` to get value set in command-line.

Comment: ${__P(testproperty,)} does not work but ${__P(testproperty)} works.

Comment: It may be worth adding that you can set a default value after the comma: `${__P(testproperty,defaultvalue)}`